# click button show next element of div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make when button is clicked, show next element(Div). 
But the problem is Div is not shown. 
what do I need to change the code ?

This is what I tried so far.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {  
    $('.wrap_tooltip .ico').click(function(){
        var $self = $(this);
        var $target = $('.wrap_tooltip .tooltip');
        $target.show();
        $target.find('.btn_close').click(function(){
            $target.focus();
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

```css
.tooltip { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrap_tooltip">
  <button>click1</button>
  <div class="tooltip">
    tooltip show
    <button class="btn_close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br>

<div class="wrap_tooltip">
  <button>click2</button>
  <div class="tooltip">
    tooltip show
    <button class="btn_close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you have no element with the class `.ico`.

Second then use `var $target = $self.next('.tooltip');` so `$target` is equal to the `.tooltip` that is next to the button.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('.wrap_tooltip .ico').click(function(){
        var $self = $(this);
        var $target = $self.next('.tooltip');
        $target.show();
    }); 
    
    $(".btn_close").click(function() {
      $(this).closest(".tooltip").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.tooltip { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrap_tooltip">
  <button class="ico">click1</button>
  <div class="tooltip">
    tooltip show
    <button class="btn_close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br>

<div class="wrap_tooltip">
  <button class="ico">click2</button>
  <div class="tooltip">
    tooltip show
    <button class="btn_close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.tooltip{ display:none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {  
    $('.wrap_tooltip button').click(function(){

        $(this).siblings(".tooltip").show();
    }); 

    $('.wrap_tooltip .btn_close').click(function(){

        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});

</script>

<div class="wrap_tooltip">
  <button>click1</button>
  <div class="tooltip">
    tooltip show
    <button class="btn_close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br>

<div class="wrap_tooltip">
  <button>click2</button>
  <div class="tooltip">
    tooltip show
    <button class="btn_close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```